# Gauge Integral: well defined?

Tags: integration, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

Given a compact space $\Omega$ and a Banach space $E$

Consider functions $f:\Omega\to E$.

Regard neighborhood gauges:
$$\delta:\Omega\to\mathcal{T}(\Omega):\quad\delta(\omega)\in\mathcal{N}(\omega)$$
and finite measurable tagged partitions:
$$\mathcal{P}^*\subseteq\mathcal{B}(\Omega):\quad\#\mathcal{P}^*<\infty$$
*(In fact, the tags are just surpressed.)*

Order gauges by inclusion:
$$\delta\leq\delta':\iff\delta(\omega)\subseteq\delta'(\omega)\quad(\omega\in\Omega)$$
and collect gauge-fine partitions:
$$\mathcal{P}^*\dashv\delta:\iff A_n\subseteq\delta(a_n)\quad(A_n\in\mathcal{P}^*)$$

Denote the partial sums by:
$$\mathcal{S}(\mathcal{P}^*)=\sum_nF(a_n)\lambda(A_n)$$
and define the gauge integral to be the limit:
$$\int_\Omega F\mathrm{d}\lambda:=\lim_\delta\{\mathcal{S}(\mathcal{P}^*)\}_{\mathcal{P}^*\dashv\delta}$$

Why is the value assigned to a gauge integral well defined (unique)?

Comment: I got the hint that for two different gauges there's always a partition fine w.r.t. both gauges. Does someone has an idea how to construct that one? The rest then follows by Hausdorff...

Comment: Take the pointwise minimum of the two gauges, which is again a gauge, and apply https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cousin%27s_theorem .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Gauges are directed:
$$\delta\wedge\delta'(\omega):=\delta(\omega)\cap\delta'(\omega)$$
and every gauge admits a partition:
$$\Omega=\bigcup_{n=1}^N\delta(a_n)=:\bigcup_{n=1}^NA_n:\quad\mathcal{P}_\delta:=\{A_1',\ldots,A_N'\}\quad(A_n':=A_n\setminus\cup_{m=1}^{n-1}A_m)$$
*(Note that compactness was necessary!)*

That is gauges induce a net of partial sums:
$$\mathcal{S}(\mathcal{P}_\delta^*):\quad{\mathcal{P}}_{\delta}^{*}\leq{\mathcal{P}'}_{\delta'}^{*'}:\iff\delta\leq\delta'$$
*(Caution: There may be no meet!)*

Concluding that the integral is well-defined in Banach space $E$.